# Chamar uma aplicação .exe em um Panel C#

Tags: c#

Para abrir uma aplicação sei que usa o seguinte código

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc");
```

Agora preciso saber como abrir a aplicação em um `Panel` em meu `Form`, de forma que não seja possível arrastá-lo para fora do `Panel` ou da minha aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Nativamente não é possível, mas você pode chamar métodos internos do `user32.dll` para que isso seja possível. Chame o método `SetPointerParent` com o executável destino e o controle que irá ser exibido.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hwc, IntPtr hwp);

protected internal IntPtr SetPointerParent(string exename, Control parent)
{
    Process p = Process.Start(exename);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    p.WaitForInputIdle();

    IntPtr hw = p.MainWindowHandle;
    IntPtr hc = parent.Handle;
    SetParent(hw, hc);
    return hw;
}
```